# SharePoint removing referenced CSS from Master Page

Tags: 2013, master-page, publishing-site, design-manager

On our development SharePoint site I can reference style sheets in our Master Page's html file. It converts successfully to the .master version.

However, our production SharePoint site strips out the referenced style sheets. The .master conversion is successful but the references to the style sheets are missing.

Does anyone know what setting handles this?

I'm adding CSS in the HTML files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/oursite/Style%20Library/site.css" />
```

Comment: How are you referencing the style sheet, can you add an example in your question

Comment: I've updated my question with the example. On our development site this works, but on our production site it doesn't.

Comment: Try mentioning type="text/css" property in link tag.